# Redirect on a SWFObject when Full Screen is clicked?

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I am using JavaScript to display a swf video, and I want to override the Full Screen button if possible, so that it redirects to another url instead of making the video full screen.  Is there a parameter that I can pass to the SWFObject that will allow me to do this? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what video player you are using, not all video players created in Flash can support this.  I recommend you elaborate your question about the specifics of the player / SWFObject, so that people can attempt to answer your question.  You might also want to consult the documentation of the Flash player you are using.